# flow+flow is a flow

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

I have the following question:
If $f$ is an $s$-$t$ flow in $(G,\mu, s, t)$ and $f'$ is an $s$-$t$ flow in $(G,\mu', s, t)$ then there exists an $s$-$t$ flow in $(G, \mu +\mu', s, t)$ of value $|f|+|f'|$. ($\mu$ and $\mu'$ are the capacities)

Intuitively I would say this is correct, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true.  To prove it, write down the linear constraints satisfied by $f$ and $f'$ and show that $f+f'$ satisfies the linear constraints that define an $s$-$t$ flow with the new capacities.

Comment: Thanks for your answer? Is this also correct, if $|f|$ and $|f'|$ are maximum flows, this means $|f|+|f'|$ is a maximum flow in $(G,\mu+\mu',s,t)$?

Comment: No, and there is a counterexample with three nodes and two arcs, where $|f|=|f’|=0$ but the maximum flow value with the new capacities is positive.

Comment: Great, thank you!